# clang-tidy treats namespace as global variable when using readability-identifier-naming

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang-tidy

I am using clang-tidy to lint source code. In the file `.clang-tidy` i defined:

```
Checks: '-*,readability-identifier-naming'
CheckOptions:
...
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.NamespacePrefix,               value: n1_        },
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.GlobalVariablePrefix,          value: g1_        },
...
```

myHeader.h:

```cpp
namespace n1_test
{
...
}
```

Linting this file with clang-tidy (tried 11.1.0, 13.0.0git(both compiled by myself) and 10.0.0(downloaded)) on `Linux Mint 19.2 (Tina)`

with:

```
clang-tidy-11.1.0 -export-fixes=fixes.txt /tmp/clangTest/mylib/source/myHeader.h -- -I/tmp/clangTest/myLib/source
```

results in:

```
 warning: invalid case style for global variable 'n1_test' [readability-identifier-naming]
namespace n1_test {
          ^~~~~~~~~~
          g1_n1_test
```

I don't understand why `NamespacePrefix` is not working and clang-tidy treats the namespace as a global variable. I also testest `NamespaceCase` and it isn't working to.

PS: According to the [documentation](https://releases.llvm.org/11.0.1/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/readability-identifier-naming.html#cmdoption-arg-namespaceprefix) this should work

Comment: Does your code compile (possibly error from elsewhere)? Else it seems to be a bug.

Comment: it compiles. Maybe i also have to mentioned, that i got also an error for including list: `.error: 'list' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
#include <list>`

Comment: It seems then that your "installation/configuration" is broken in some ways. Providing system info (mainly windows or *nix) might help I think. And where are standard headers.

Comment: Linux Mint 19.2 (Tina)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can't use clang-tidy directly on header files. Instead i have to check the cpp file and have to add `-header-filter=.*` to also check the headers:

```
clang-tidy-11.1.0 -header-filter=.* -export-fixes=fixes.txt /tmp/clangTest/mylib/source/main.cpp -- -I/tmp/clangTest/myLib/source
```