# CLang tidy does not recognize namespace keyword and interprets it as a variable

Tags: c++, clang-tidy, platformio

I am ramping up a Platform IO project. Within there I am using clang-tidy for different checks ([see documentation for PIO clang-tidy here](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/plus/check-tools/clang-tidy.html#supported-checks)).

Given the folder structure

```
- .
-- include
-- src
```

I placed a header file in the include folder, called ISomeInterface.h
The content looks like this:

```
#pragma once

namespace some_namespace { // interface declaration
}
```

When I run pio check (invokes clang-tidy) I get the warning

```
variable 'some_namespace' is non-const and globally accessible, consider making it const  [cppcoreguidelines-avoid-non-const-global-variables]
```

The Question is: Why is CLang not recognizing the namespace keyword? I found a possible solution here [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275717/clang-tidy-treats-namespace-as-global-variable-when-using-readability-identifier) that states

```
can't use clang-tidy directly on header files. Instead i have to check the cpp file and have to add -header-filter=.* to also check the headers
```

But this did not work for me :(

Comment: Can you share exact command with which `clang-tidy` is invoked? I don't know PIO, but it should be somewhere in the logs. (My blind guess is for some reason clang-tidy is treating your header as C source, not C++)

Comment: Hi, I just recognized the option to output some information via clangtidy flag -export-fixes=.fixes.txt Now there I can see the error "clang 'unknown type name ''namespace''"' just before the user visible warning "variable 'some_namespace' is non-const and globally accessible, consider making it const  [cppcoreguidelines-avoid-non-const-global-variables]". That sounds like a c<>c++ problem to me as well. I will check that.